# Application using excel interop only collects and writes data one time

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have written a small application that collects data from a PLC and then writes that data to excel.  When I open the application the first time I collect the data it works perfectly but, if I try to collect again it does not place any data into the file and just does a save as on the template file.  If I restart the application it works again but, only 1 time.  Here is the simplified code.

```
    // Open the Excel application
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    // Open the workbook
    string filelocation = Properties.Settings.Default.templateLocation;
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filelocation);

    //Define the worksheet and open
    Excel.Worksheet sh =       (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["MULTIPLE_SHOT_DATA"];

    //Saves as dialog control to get filename and location
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.filedir != null || Properties.Settings.Default.filedir != "")
    {
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.filedir;
    }

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Worksheet (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File";
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    //Column loop should be 24 or 36 for different ball machines
    for (int columnloop = 0; columnloop < 24; columnloop++)
    {
        int inbounddata = columnloop;
        string inbounddatastring = inbounddata.ToString();
        _myItem.HWTagType = TagType.AUTO;
        _myItem.HWTagName = "Ball[" + inbounddatastring + ",0]";
        _myItem.Elements = 100;

        try
        {
            // Call Item.Read method
            _myItem.Read();

            // For atomic types, each Item.Values element represents one atomic value.
            if (!_myItem.Values[0].GetType().IsArray)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _myItem.Elements; i++)
            {
            int inboundcolumn = excelcolumn;
            fint = i + 1;
            sh.Cells[fint, inboundcolumn] = _myItem.Values[i];
        }

    }
    // For structured types (UDT, PDT, and System), each Item.Values element represents an array of    bytes
    else
    {
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    AddEvent("Error, Item.Quality is " + _myItem.Quality.ToString();
}
finally
{
this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
}
}
//Save as and close active file
workbook.SaveAs(@Properties.Settings.Default.filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sh);
workbook.Close();
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);

// Quit the Excel application
excel.Quit();
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excel);
```

I would expect that this would work multiple times but, it does not.

Comment: Nevermind.  Wasn't resetting the cell placement variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only going to execute this one time.  You need to provide the user of your application the ability to execute this code as many times as they want.  Is this a console program? If so, you need to add a loop and then wait for use to "Press any key..." and re-execute the code.

If it is a WinForms or WPF application then you need to show a window, add a button and call this code in the Clicked event.

Also, you could create a class named `LineSampler`

```
public class LineSampler 
{
    public void PullDataFromMachines()
    {
         //copy all your code here.
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
var sampler = new LineSampler();
//infinite loop....
for(;;)
{
    sampler.PullDataFromMachines();
    System.Console.ReadLine();  // wait for user to hit [ENTER] and repeat.  user can CTRL+C to break out.
}
```